# How to re-fire a woocommerce webhook

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, webhooks, hook-woocommerce

We have some 'action' type webhooks setup, but sometimes we want to resend the data originally sent via webhook. For instance the webhook starts an automation process, but failed, we need to start ti again. To do this I added a custom order actions to the admin meta box, but now I need them to actually (re)fire the webhook.

```php
function pwk_wc_add_order_meta_box_action( $actions ) {
    global $theorder;

    // continue if the order completed, processing or refunded
    if ( $theorder->has_status('processing') || $theorder->has_status('completed') || $theorder->has_status('refunded')  ) {
        
        $actions['wc_resend_order_webhook'] = __( 'Refire this order webhook', 'text-domain' );
        
        return $actions;
        
    } else {
        return $actions;
    }
}
```

My webhook is setup like this:

| Name | action.woocommerce_payment_complete |
| --- | --- |
| Status | Active |
| Topic | Action |
| Action event | woocommerce_payment_complete |

What action can I call to run a webhook? I don't want the order emails to be sent only the webhook to fire. In my situation it's the "woocommerce_payment_complete" but really how does one refire a webhook for any action or topic?

EDIT 1: So I created a new webhook with the Action event `woocommerce_order_action_wc_resend_order_webhook`, and then added something to the function:

```php
function pwk_process_resend_order_webhook_meta_box_action( $order ) {
    
     // add the order note
    $message = sprintf( __( 'Order resent to integromat.', 'text-domain' ));
    $order->add_order_note( $message );
    $arg = $order->get_order_number();
    return $arg;
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_action_wc_resend_order_webhook', 'pwk_process_resend_order_webhook_meta_box_action' );
```

Although this does fire a webhook, it looks like it's an array not a simple order id:

```
{
  "action": "woocommerce_order_action_wc_resend_order_webhook",
  "arg": []
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution was to exploit the woocommerce_order_action as it allows new actions, then running a `do_action` which creates a action with the sole purpose of firing the webhook. The action name `woocommerce_order_action_fire_webhook_order` is made up
i.e. `<woocommerce_order_action_>anything_you_want` works too

```
function pwk_process_resend_order_webhook_meta_box_action( $order ) {
    
    $message = sprintf( __( 'Order details resent via webhook.', 'text-domain' ));
    $order->add_order_note( $message );
    
    do_action( 'woocommerce_order_action_fire_webhook_order', $order->get_order_number() );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_action_wc_resend_order_webhook', 'pwk_process_resend_order_webhook_meta_box_action' );
```

Then also create a webhook with the `action` type for the event `woocommerce_order_action_fire_webhook_order`

tbh I'm not entirely sure why this works, so any comments or edits are most welcome.